# Prove that for a random variable, Rényi entropy for $\alpha = \infty$ converges to min-entropy

Tags: probability, logarithms, entropy

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy), Rényi entropy for a random variable $X$ is defined as (for $\alpha \ge 0, \alpha \ne 1)$:

$$
H_\alpha(X) = \frac{1}{1 - \alpha} \log\left(\sum_i^n p_i^\alpha\right).
$$

Shannon entropy is a special case of this entropy for $\lim_{\alpha \to 1}$. The proof of this is present in this [math.stackexchange link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536351/proving-renyi-entropy-properties). Now, I am interested in another special case of Rényi entropy where $\lim_{\alpha \to \infty}$. It is stated in the wikipedia that, in this case, Rényi entropy converges to min-entropy($H_\infty(X)$), which is:

$$
H_\infty(X) = -\log \underset{i}{\max} p_i . 
$$
Now, here is my question. How do I prove that the following result holds?
$$
\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} H_\alpha(X) = \lim_{\alpha \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 - \alpha} \log\left(\sum_i^n p_i^\alpha\right) = -\log \underset{i}{\max} p_i = H_\infty(X)
$$
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sketch of an argument, I will leave a formal proof to a more capable contributor

1. for $\alpha \gg 1$, you have that

$$
\frac{1}{1 - \alpha} \approx -\frac{1}{a} \tag{1}
$$

2. Since $0 \le p_i \le 1$, if $p_i < p_j$, then $p_i^a < p_j^a$. That means that of all the $p$'s, only the largest one ($\max_i p_i$) will survive inside the sum, all other terms will become negligible as $a$ increases. That is, for $a \gg 1$

$$
\sum_i p_i^a \approx \max_i p_i^a \tag{2}
$$

3. Now put together (1) and (2), for $a \gg 1$ you get

$$
H_a(X) \approx -\frac{1}{a} \log (\max_i p_i)^a = -\log (\max_i p_i)^{a/a} = -\log \max_i p_i
$$

Comment: This is clear enough, thanks caverac.

Comment: @QuestionEverything happy to help